# How to load existing Java code and run it within the program

Tags: java, processing, file-handling

I’m creating a mock OS in Processing 3, and I want my OS to be able to download and run apps which have been written by a third party.

Basically, I want my OS to be able to load an application file from the user’s computer, get the Java code from the file and run that code within a window object I have created within the OS. Is there any way I can load Java code and run it within the program currently running?

I have hard coded a Settings, Calender and Notes app into my OS, but ideally they would also be kept in files of their own and loaded during the bootup sequence, as would any other applications the user has chosen to install on the OS.

Comment: You might want to look into java class loaders: https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders (at 4.1). Since Processing is based on java this should work.

Comment: @svdragster Thanks. This looks lovely and complex, I’ll look into it

Comment: It will help to make use of Processing's registerMethod() and unregisterMethod().

Comment: @micycle I can’t find those on the processing.org/reference page, care to drop a link to any documentation you know of?

Comment: @ChristianLoizou The method is described [here](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PApplet.html#registerMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) in the Javadocs. The idea is your apps can define their own draw() and mouse/key event methods without you having to write something like app.draw() in the parent PApplet draw loop. Note that the method name must correspond to that in Processing - your draw loop must be named draw(). The `target` parameter would be an instance of a third-party app in your case.

Comment: @micycle Brilliant, thanks.